# My Xcode version 8.0 crashes

Tags: objective-c, xcode, crash, xcode8

My Xcode crashes, After crash occur, I updated it to the latest version, i.e 8.0
But it doesn't stop crashing.

```
Process:               Xcode [528]
Path:                  /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
Identifier:            com.apple.dt.Xcode
Version:               8.0 (11246)
Build Info:            IDEFrameworks-11246000000000000~3
App Item ID:           497799835
App External ID:       818744938
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           Xcode [528]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-10-08 14:08:34.396 +0500
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.6 (15G1004)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        844112AA-C988-B86A-8002-19E0765599D4

Time Awake Since Boot: 180 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

 Application Specific Information:ProductBuildVersion: 8A218a
 ASSERTION FAILURE in     /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks- 11246/IDEKit/Application/IDEWindowMenuController.m:101
 Details:  itemName should be a non-empty string, but it's an empty string
 Object:   <IDEWindowMenuController>
 Method:        +titleForItemWithURL:name:image:parentLocations:presentedParentLocationCount:includeIconInTitles:
Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fc74ad179f0>{number = 1, name = main}
Hints:   None
```

Following is the Back Trace Report:

```
Backtrace:
0   -[IDEAssertionHandler     handleFailureInMethod:object:fileName:lineNumber:assertionSignature:messageFormat:arguments:] (in IDEKit)
  1   _DVTAssertionHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  2   _DVTAssertionFailureHandler (in DVTFoundation)
  3   +[IDEWindowMenuController   titleForItemWithURL:name:image:parentLocations:presentedParentLocationCount:includeIconInTitles:] (in IDEKit)
  4   __90+[IDEWindowMenuController  _createAttributedTitlesForItemDictionaries:includeIconInTitles:]_block_invoke (in IDEKit)
  5   __53-[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:]_block_invoke (in CoreFoundation)
  6   -[__NSArrayM enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:] (in CoreFoundation)
  7   +[IDEWindowMenuController _createAttributedTitlesForItemDictionaries:includeIconInTitles:] (in IDEKit)
  8   -[IDEWindowMenuController _windowMenuItemsWithIconInTitles:] (in IDEKit)
  9   -[IDEApplicationController applicationDockMenu:] (in IDEKit)
 10   -[NSApplication _createDockMenu:] (in AppKit)
 11   __44-[NSApplication _copyPublicPersistentUIInfo]_block_invoke (in AppKit)
 12   __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ (in CoreFoundation)
 13   __CFRunLoopDoBlocks (in CoreFoundation)
 14   __CFRunLoopRun (in CoreFoundation)
 15   CFRunLoopRunSpecific (in CoreFoundation)
 16   RunCurrentEventLoopInMode (in HIToolbox)
 17   ReceiveNextEventCommon (in HIToolbox)
 18   _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter (in HIToolbox)
 19   _DPSNextEvent (in AppKit)
 20   -[NSApplication _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in AppKit)
 21   -[DVTApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] (in DVTKit)
 22   -[NSApplication run] (in AppKit)
 23   NSApplicationMain (in AppKit)
 24   start (in libdyld.dylib)

 abort() called

 Application Specific Signatures:
 ![(itemName) isEqualToString:@""]
```

Comment: With such a crash, it would probably be wise to submit a bug report to Apple about it. They're ultimately the only people who can actually push a fix for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with these please :

1. Open Xcode
2. Preferences
3. Locations
4. The Derived Data option will tell you where your directory is
5. Delete that directory
6. Try to open your project

And check this thread also: 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/39603

Answer (score 1):

This crash occurred due to problem in my project, so i was beginner, and I assumed that problem is in my X-Code.
The Project loaded automatically and causes crash to occur.
After opening some one previous project, and tried to stop this crashed project, Crashing stopped.. :P